# Looking for Hadiths like these for Husbands, instead of Wives

Tags: source-identification

We've hadiths like:

> If I were to command anyone to make prostration before another I would
> command women to prostrate themselves before their husbands, because
> of the special right over them given to husbands by Allah.
>  [[Source]](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/12/95)
>
> When a man invites his wife to his bed and she does not come, and he
> (the husband) spends the sight being angry with her, the angels curse
> her until morning. [[Source](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1436d)]
>
> There are three people whose prayers will not be accepted by Allah,
> nor do any good deed of theirs risen up to heaven: a fleeing slave
> until he returns to his master and helps him, a woman whose husband is
> angry with her until he is pleased with her, and a drunkard until he
> becomes conscious. [Ibn Hibban]
>
> The first things a woman is called to account for on the Day of
> Judgment are her prayers and her (relations with her) husband. [Suyuti's Jami-al-Kabir]
>
> It is not lawful for a woman to fast (voluntarily) when her husband is
> present, except by his permission nor permit anyone into his house
> except with his permission. [[Source](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5192)]
>
> The Prophet() said, "Isn't the witness of a woman equal to half of
> that of a man?" The women said, "Yes." He said, "This is because of
> the **deficiency of a woman's mind**. [ [Source](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2658) ]

I want to know, are there any Hadiths **like the above**, but for husbands? (**Please notice, I am not asking for Hadiths like 'Husband should treat his wife fairly'**, but Hadiths with the severity of relationship and responsability like above, especially the first Hadith).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are hadiths for wives as well.

> Abu Hurairah (may Allah be pleased with him) narrated that the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings be upon him) said: “The most complete of the believers in faith, is the one with the best character. And the best of you are those who are best to their women.”(At-Tirmidhi and authenticated by Al-Albani)

> Ibn `Abbas (may Allah be pleased with him) narrated that the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said: “The best among you is the best towards his wife, and I am the best of you to my wives.” (Ibn Majah and authenticated by Al-Albani)

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) narrated that the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said : “A believer must not hate a believing woman (i.e., his wife); if he dislikes one of her traits he will be pleased with another.”

> `Abdullah ibn` Amr ibn Al-`As (May Allah be pleased with them) narrated that the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said: “The world is but a (quick passing) enjoyment; and the best enjoyment of the world is (to have) a pious wife.”

> Anas ibn Malik reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Whoever Allah provides with a righteous wife, Allah has assisted him in half of his religion. Let him fear Allah regarding the second half.”

There may be more. Allah knows best.

Comment: Pls read & understand the question carefully before answering